In QSSTV on Linux, how do I configure control of PTT using RTS via an FTDI cable?
I have an FTDI cable, whose RTS is connected through an opto isolator to my PTT.
When I connect it to a Windows PC and run MMSSTV, it works, but inverted (PTT is on when not sending and off when sending). That's an easy fix, but it demonstrates that the hardware is solid.
When I connect it to my Linux laptop, QSSTV does not appear to make any changes to the RTS pin at all. I verified with a DMM: it puts out 3.3V regardless.
Initially, I had an error writing to the port, but I fixed that by adding my user to the dialup and tty groups. I can execute
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 -a

which shows I have rights. ttyUSB0 is the only USB tty port on my system and it disapears when I unplug the cable, so I know that's the correct port.
I have tried all sorts of combinations of +RTS +DTR -RTS -DTR and nothing causes the +3.3V to change on the RTS line.
Are there any other suggestions, please?

Thank you, @Mike Waters. :-)

When I used that on Linux Mint, I had no FTDI cable. I forget all the details, but the computer simply controlled the rig with VOX. Is that possible?

I have two radios. Kenwood and Quanshang. Unfortunately (as I'm learning is often the case) neither engages its vox circuit unless the audio is coming through the mic. Thanks.

Just checking: did you remember to select the "Enable PTT serial interface" checkbox to the left of the settings you're looking at?

Fair question. Yes, that was the first thing I spotted. Thanks.

Try this workaround: run
rigctld -m 1 -p /dev/ttyUSB0 --ptt-type RTS

and then in qsstv, instead of using PTT serial, check "Enable Hamlib Cat Interface", set "Radio model" to 2 (Hamlib NET rigctl), "Serial port/host" to "localhost", and "PTT control via" to "CAT (Data port)".
that delegates the PTT control to hamlib, by telling rigctld to run with a "dummy" radio (that accepts CAT commands like frequency changes without actually doing anything), but with a serial PTT device.
If that doesn't work, the problem is probably at the driver level. Seeing as how the Linux FT232 driver does work in general, that would make me suspect a less-than-genuine FTDI chip.

I see why this wold work. I think the FTDI chip is genuine. I have a suspicion the RTS output is a pull-up or float type output. I fixed it by a weak pull-down resistor! Most folk use a transistor to sink the ground for PTT, but I used an opto-isolator. I suspect the type if chip I used didn't "encourage" the output low. With my apologies, I don't know when I'll get an opportunity to test it.
